# What is the difference between :0 and :1 of MAM protocols in ejabberd?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I see some protocols using both like mam. How does this versioning work? I cant find any documents about this except in xmpp specs they use :2 on mam. What is the equivalent of these to the xmpp specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find old versions of XEPs [here](https://xmpp.org/extensions/attic/).

Find files starting with "xep-0313-" if you're insterested in old versions of MAM.